# Django runserver error (sqlite2 & sqlite3)

Tags: python, django

I just installed Django and I'm following this tutorial: [Django tutorial](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter02.html.)

When I type "python3.3 manage.py runserver" this happens:

```
ninaolo@ninaolo-VirtualBox:~/Documents/Django-projekt/testprojekt$ python3.3 manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as Database
ImportError: No module named 'pysqlite2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 32, in <module>
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 26, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1584, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 584, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1022, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1003, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_for_loader_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 868, in _load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite, site
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 48, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 96, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 264, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 124, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 198, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 35, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): %s" % exc)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): No module named '_sqlite3'
```

And if I type "python manage.py runserver" (I have both Python 2.7 and 3.3):

```
ninaolo@ninaolo-VirtualBox:~/Documents/Django-projekt/testprojekt$ python2.7 manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Does anybody understand what's wrong here?

Comment: The Django Book is out of date, I wouldn't recommend using it any more. If you are new to Django, I would recommend following the [Django Tutorial for Django 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/) which is written for Django 1.6 and Python 2.6.5 or 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you have neither `pysqlite2` nor `sqlite3` installed, but you've configured Django to use a SQLite database; one of those database drivers is required in order to use a SQLite database.

Also, you have apparently only installed Django in your Python 3 environment. Package library directories are not shared between different versions of Python — each has its own, so packages you want to use with multiple versions of Python need to be installed separately for each version.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well I intended to configure it with MySQL but now I realise I have to do some changes in the settings to be able to run the runserver command. Thanks!